# would be possible to re-post the 2014 fusion wiring diagram?

Tags: ford, lights, fusion, wiring-diagram

RE: 2014 Ford Fusion Titanium
Driver side fender mounted tail lamp. Outer LEDs not lighted.
Could you re-post the wiring diagram for 2014 Fusion?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: can you provide a picture showing which light isn't working?

Comment: Ben, I'm new to site--having trouble posting a jpeg. The light in question is driver side, fender mounted. The outer LED ring does not light. Looking for wire diagram so I may disassemble and inspect

Answer (score 1):

I only have 2012 info, but perhaps it helps.

However, if only *part* of a LED lamp is not working, the issue is likely a failed tail lamp assembly, which is probably not easily repairable.  Is it the entire running lamp section that isn't working, or just some LEDs around the outside?  Do the brake lights and turn signals still work?

Try turning on the hazard lamps and observe what works left vs right.

[image]

Comment: That’s fairly similar to the ‘14 diagram the difference is they use FETs in the BCM for each individual light now

Comment: all lights except outside diameter function. I'm still looking for the wire associations in the connector plug